# PhpDocumentor. Class type annotation

Tags: php, phpstorm, phpdoc

I have factory that looks for class and returns it. I return class as string. How shall I correctly annotate in PhpDocumentor that returned type is a class? I always create interface that describes static methods of class (as it is common for TypeScript). But PhpStorm says that it is wrong way! Need your help. Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: You return a string .. so it's what you need to annotate in `@return`. There is no special "this is a string that represents specific class". You current approach is fine (good thinking and will work when used inline/typehinting local variable) but IDE thinks otherwise.  P.S. You can try `string|IStatsSummaryClass` .. but since you have just a single return statement ... it may (should) trigger another warning.

Comment: P.P.S. 1) Try some code formatting, use new lines to separate logical blocks etc -- it's hard to read such compact code (especially if you are not familiar with it). 2) Why double quotes for `$namespace`? But even then -- why only some of `\ ` are escaped?

Comment: 1) I prefer short and compact code. Think it is better than too long style with all that formatting. Don't judge me too hard. xDD
2) Is it better to write `$namespace` in single quotes? (I missed some escape symbol at screenshot.)

Comment: *"Is it better to write $namespace in single quotes?"* I mean -- because there is `\ ` symbol in namespace .. you have to escape it to be on a safe side (e.g.  `\t` is interpreted as TAB symbol .. and you have it in your namespace) . In single quotes `\t` is just `\t`. *"I prefer short and compact code"* That's fine -- personal preferences. I was referring to readability when you giving it to others (like now). But in general -- code must be read easily, by anyone and not just you. You come back to this code in 1 year and you will see that it's hard to read it even for you...

Comment: Small side note: "PhpDocumentor" is a software package that generates documentation. It has no relation to PhpStorm (IDE has no integration with it). But the actual doc comments system is called "PHPDoc" -- that's more appropriate in this context (question text/subject).

Comment: I may be missing something but I can't see the benefit of annotating the `IStatsSummaryClass` interface as return type for a function that returns a string. You'll just get incorrect documentation hints and code-completion you can't use because it doesn't work. :-?

Comment: I need `IStatsSummaryClass` interface to describe interface of the class. Client code, that gets class, represents by string, have to understand what actions it is possible to make at this class. This pattern is common for TypeScript and I decided it would be correct to use it for PHP. This is my opinion. If you know better way tell me please. :-)

Comment: How does that string actually become a class instance?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Well ... for static methods it works: https://postimg.cc/image/rwvywy13h/ or https://3v4l.org/bPYMh

Comment: @LazyOne Alright, $a::doThis(); was the bit I was missing. It's probably obvious though I'll say in my defence that the question was not stating it explicitly <:-)